# What is a mapping between natural numbers and valid simply typed lambda calculus terms?

Tags: algorithm, search, functional-programming, enumeration, lambda-calculus

Is there any efficient algorithm that maps between well-typed, closed terms of the simply typed lambda calculus and natural numbers? For example, using bruijn indexes (and probably on incorrect order):

```
0 → (λ 0)
1 → (λ (λ (0 1)))
2 → (λ (λ (1 0)))
3 → (λ 0 (λ 0))
4 → (λ (λ 0) 0)
5 → (λ (λ 1) 0)
6 → ... so on
```

Related questions: is there an algorithm that maps between natural numbers and **normalized** terms of the simply typed lambda calculus? Also, the same questions applied to the untyped lambda calculus.

Comment: Does it have to be bijective? If so, I don't believe there can be any efficient solution.

Comment: If recognizing normalized terms is not computable, then you're likely to be unhappy with enumeration algorithms.

Comment: By "maps between" do you mean two maps, one going in each direction (probably where they are inverses of each other, making it an isomorphism)? Also, do you want it just restricted to Church numerals or do you want it to work for any arbitrary lambda term? It sounds like you're looking for the latter, which (if I'm right on the first thing I asked) seems to be asking if the set of all lambda calculus terms is countable.

Comment: Yes, two maps. A function "natToLambda" and its inverse, "lambdaToNat". And yes, I want the latter. It is countable!

Comment: Do you need `lambdaToNat` to be surjective?

Comment: Yes... bijective even...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binary Lambda Calculus defines a binary encoding for any closed term in the untyped lambda calculus, and also suggests a bijection between natural numbers and binary strings, but the former is not surjective.
Still, the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0379
"Counting Terms in the Binary Lambda Calculus"
might yield efficient ranking/unranking mappings.

Comment: John, isn't there any algorithm that takes an int (a nat...) and translates it into a lambda term, and it s reverse? So that every nat has a corresponding lambda term and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the highly context-sensitive nature of typed lambda calculus I would be surprised if there were an efficient algorithm, or rather a "natural" efficient algorithm.

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.2610) has nice formulae for counting *untyped* lambda terms and from that they derive a fairly simple function for enumerating untyped terms. They also provide a counting function for normal forms which should be easy to adapt to a generating function too. Unfortunately, they only make a typed generator function by filtering that which is absurdly expensive (one of the results of the paper is just how absurd it is).

As for a more efficient way to generate typed terms, my advice would be to generate *typing derivations* instead of terms and then type checking them.